# Iterate through child <li> and remove class?

Tags: jquery, css

How can we iterate through child `<li>` find and remove css class?

```
<ul id="SideMenu" class="outer">
<li>
    <p class="top">My Account</p>
    <ul class="inner">
        <li id="MyAccount" class="active"><a href="#">My Account Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <p>Demographics</p>
    <ul class="inner">
        <li id="Addresses" ><a href="#">Addresses</a></li>
        <li id="ContactInformation">
            <a href="~/ContactInformation/Index">Contact Information</a>
        </li>
        <li id="ChangePassword"><a href="#">Change Password</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I tried this, but it didn't work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#SideMenu li").each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        });
    });
</script>
```

### update

Actually I want remove class and add dynamically to another `<li>` based on my condition.

Comment: Works for me. Any console errors? http://jsfiddle.net/23n02L2m/. Have you included jQuery file? How are you checking whether the class is removed?

Comment: Works for me too. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNNbXZ

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ItsMeSri/krev8q1m did not worked

Comment: You are not using my code. Did you check my fiddle? And please include jQuery file in your fiddle.

Comment: @James123: The problem is that you didn't add jQuery to the Fiddle, so of course is not working ;) http://jsfiddle.net/krev8q1m/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).find('.active').removeClass("active");
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/krev8q1m/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Should be working, but if you need to be more specific:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#SideMenu li").each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("active").addClass('baz');
        });
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT:** There is no problem with the code, the problem is that you haven't set Jquery in jsFiddle, next time check the console and you will know: http://jsfiddle.net/krev8q1m/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative in plain javascript:

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#SideMenu li')).map(function(data){
    return data.classList.remove('active');
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkkd0pgw/)